# Handle missing keys with numeric types in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

For mutable types, such as list, instead of using `if else`, we can deal with missing key issues like this:

```
dic = {'key1':[1, 2], 'key2':[1]}
dic.setdefault('key3', []).append(1)
```

which only checks `'key3'` in `dic` only once.

But for immutable types, such as integer, we cannot use `setdefault()` like this:

```
dic = {'key1':3, 'key2':5}
dic.setdefault('key3', 0) += 1
```

Since `setdefault()` will return the integer `0` instead of variable `dic['key3']`

I'm not sure how to deal with it elegantly, for example the best I can do is like this:

```
dic = {'key1':3, 'key2':5}
dic['key3'] = 1 if 'key3' not in dic else dic['key3'] + 1
```

But this code checks `'key3'` in `dic` twice and also use extra memory for `dic['key3'] + 1` if `'key3'` exists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)? Note that this is really about mutability vs immutability - a `tuple` is still iterable, but would have the same problem you see with integers. Also checking `'key3' in dic` twice is really not a big deal; lookups by key in a dictionary are `O(1)` because it's a hash table (see [this classic PyCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68) for more info).

Comment: Thanks much for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **use `.get(..)`** to specify a *default value*, like:

```
dic['key3'] = dic.get('key3',0) + 1
```

`.get(key,default=None)` performs a lookup on the dictionary. In case it fails to find the `key`, it will return the `default`.

But I think in this case, you better **use a `Counter`**:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter({'key1':3, 'key2':5})
counter['key3'] += 1
```

A counter *assumes* that if a key is not present in the database, its value is zero.

Comment: Yes, `Counter` is better than `defaultdict(int)`.

Comment: Thanks! `counter` works just fine when the default value is zero. But I think `dic['key3'] = dic.get('key3',0) + 1` still checks `dic` twice and uses extra memory.

Comment: @DongxuZhang: no usually `.get(..)` has its own efficient implementation: it works faster than `dic['key3'] if 'key3' in dic else 0`. And `dic['a'] += 1` will also check the dictionary twice.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh, I see. since integer is immutable, `+=`  will falls back to calling  `__add__`. Thanks~